# How to drop into REPL from a node script

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've been reading through http://nodejs.org/api/repl.html , but unless I'm missing something, I'm not sure if you can start a script and when you hit a breakpoint drip into the repl. eg:

```
app.get('/', function(req, res) {

try {

  var bucket = [];
  var targets = require('url').parse(req.url);
  console.log('this is the outside ',url);
  //// break here and drop into repl ///
  emitter.getTarget = function(url) {
    var self = this;
    console.log('this is the ',url);
```

Answer (score 2):

When debugging, instead of using the repl module, you can drop into a repl on breakpoint by running your script as:

`node debug myscript.js`

This will, on breakpoint, enter into a debugger prompt where you can type `repl` and then you can inspect the current scope and do some basic debugging operations.

[Node's docs](http://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html) provide a detailed information on what's possible, so I suggest you take a look at them and have fun!

**Update:**

If you are not so much interested in the repl itself but in a good way to inspect your code at a given breakpoint, there is always [node-inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector) - an excellent debugger for Node.js that works with any WebKit-based browser and provides a wide variety of code inspection (not a repl, though, but you can still inspect variables at a given breakpoint or modify them at runtime, for example).

Comment: how do i get it to break on an exception?